# Split Array into two equal half and same order in Jython

Tags: jython

I have an array as below and I would like to split it into two equal array in the same order in jython. For example the below array is of length 160 and I would like to split it into two array with length 80 each.

```
[325, 1127, 546, 721, 840, 613, 1036, 1001, 581, 926, 25, 508, 1188, 1104, 295, 994, 192,274, 1135, 632, 547, 185, 837, 669, 98, 564, 313, 43,975, 962, 409, 668, 598, 384, 703, 375, 841, 519, 593, 647, 1026, 1178, 307, 319, 1119, 381, 907, 1010, 758, 158, 280, 403, 599, 352, 190, 738,821, 1087, 506, 636, 672, 122, 203, 433, 630, 1049, 490, 265, 880, 378, 904, 261, 1056, 499, 483, 768, 1033, 510, 231, 1099, 567, 753, 1156, 96,82, 246, 675, 1213, 167, 1117, 930, 714, 1042, 299, 812, 575, 1146, 798, 405, 885, 1180, 462, 1210, 172, 754, 119, 91, 200, 1199, 127, 687, 452, 788, 52, 733, 713, 83, 1123, 68, 24, 722, 1029, 605, 585, 1171, 542, 1084, 652, 958, 839, 191, 699, 219,1096, 1216, 974, 1211, 1196, 1118, 497, 764, 1141, 346, 125, 390, 1066, 1016, 199, 932, 129, 230, 84, 27, 110, 806, 637, 769, 401, 1191, 211]
```

Expected Output

```
Array 1 = [325, 1127, 546, 721, 840, 613, 1036, 1001, 581, 926, 25, 508, 1188, 1104, 295, 994, 192,274, 1135, 632, 547, 185, 837, 669, 98, 564, 313, 43,975, 962, 409, 668, 598, 384, 703, 375, 841, 519, 593, 647, 1026, 1178, 307, 319, 1119, 381, 907, 1010, 758, 158, 280, 403, 599, 352, 190, 738,821, 1087, 506, 636, 672, 122, 203, 433, 630, 1049, 490, 265, 880, 378, 904, 261, 1056, 499, 483, 768, 1033, 510, 231, 1099]
Array 2 = [567, 753, 1156, 96,82, 246, 675, 1213, 167, 1117, 930, 714, 1042, 299, 812, 575, 1146, 798, 405, 885, 1180, 462, 1210, 172, 754, 119, 91, 200, 1199, 127, 687, 452, 788, 52, 733, 713, 83, 1123, 68, 24, 722, 1029, 605, 585, 1171, 542, 1084, 652, 958, 839, 191, 699, 219,1096, 1216, 974, 1211, 1196, 1118, 497, 764, 1141, 346, 125, 390, 1066, 1016, 199, 932, 129, 230, 84, 27, 110, 806, 637, 769, 401, 1191, 211]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findSplitPoint(arr, n) :
    leftSum = 0
    for i in range(0, n) :
        leftSum += arr[i]
 
    rightSum = 0
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1) :
      
        rightSum += arr[i]
   
        leftSum -= arr[i] 
   
        if (rightSum == leftSum) :
            return i 
   
 
    return -1
   
def printTwoParts(arr, n) :
    splitPoint = findSplitPoint(arr, n)
   
    if (splitPoint == -1 or splitPoint == n ) :
        print ("Not Possible") 
        return
  
    for i in range (0, n) :
        if(splitPoint == i) :
            print ("")
        print (arr[i], end = " ")         
   
arr = [325, 1127, 546, 721, 840, 613, 1036, 1001, 581, 926, 25, 508, 1188, 1104, 295, 994, 192,274, 1135, 632, 547, 185, 837, 669, 98, 564, 313, 43,975, 962, 409, 668, 598, 384, 703, 375, 841, 519, 593, 647, 1026, 1178, 307, 319, 1119, 381, 907, 1010, 758, 158, 280, 403, 599, 352, 190, 738,821, 1087, 506, 636, 672, 122, 203, 433, 630, 1049, 490, 265, 880, 378, 904, 261, 1056, 499, 483, 768, 1033, 510, 231, 1099, 567, 753, 1156, 96,82, 246, 675, 1213, 167, 1117, 930, 714, 1042, 299, 812, 575, 1146, 798, 405, 885, 1180, 462, 1210, 172, 754, 119, 91, 200, 1199, 127, 687, 452, 788, 52, 733, 713, 83, 1123, 68, 24, 722, 1029, 605, 585, 1171, 542, 1084, 652, 958, 839, 191, 699, 219,1096, 1216, 974, 1211, 1196, 1118, 497, 764, 1141, 346, 125, 390, 1066, 1016, 199, 932, 129, 230, 84, 27, 110, 806, 637, 769, 401, 1191, 211]
n = len(arr)
printTwoParts(arr, n)
```

source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-array-two-equal-sum-subarrays/